# HTML page to show menu bar always

Tags: html

Hi All,

I am trying to develop a simple HTML page for the test results. I am very new to HTML development so i might sound really dump with this question.

My aim is to use some thing like frameset available in HTML but point it to the internal links (href). Or some thing like a navigation bar that is always present on the Top of the HTML page or Vertical from which I can point to different sections inside HTML Page. I don't want to divide my HTML page into multiple pages. I want to keep it as a single HTML page.

I would appreciate  for some help in this regards,

Answer (score 3):

You can use a div with the CSS `position: fixed; top: 0` set.  This will allow the div to "stick" to the top of the page, regardless of where the document is scrolled.

Comment: If your navigationbar has an own bg-color and you want it over the whole width, you should also add left;0 and right:0;

Answer (score 2):

You can use anchors to navigate to separate parts of the document. For example:

```
<a href="#section1">Section 1</a>
<div>
    <a name="section1" id="section1"></a>
    Whatever section 1 might contain here.
</div>
```

As for making the navigation persisent (i.e. fixed position), you can use the `position: fixed` CSS set. See the jsFiddle sampel here > http://jsfiddle.net/PWP2T/

And the code:

```
div#mynav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: #ff00ff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}
```